# Unable to retrieve Request.Form data

Tags: asp.net, request.form

I am not able to retrieve Request.Form["SomeKey"] when the application is deployed on dev server. Application is hosted on IIS 8 and code is written in C#. Please note that I am able to see the form data in the browser tool.

Comment: Share the code. Are you passing the names of the inputs?

Comment: var rawInput = Request.Form["TestResponse"]; I am able to see TestResponse in the request header under form data

Comment: @swapnasharma, No one can give a solution, with this code. try to explain your scenario with some appropriate code

Comment: To implement single sign on we redirect the logged in user to a login page where user is authenticated against the AD and that login page posts a decrypted XML to our page. On our application page load I am trying to retrieve that decrypted XML to extract user info. But I always get a null value for Request.Form["TestResponse"]; If I debug in browser tool I am able to see the "TestResponse" in the request header in form data. This is working on some other applications hosted on different server. This makes me think that is there any IIS settings/handles that I have to check?